# What is minimum Version support to Ms Office of VSTO Add-In created in VS 2013?

Tags: c#, vsto

I want to create a Add-In. I will create in VS 2013. I just don't know what is minimum version support of Ms Office.

Can anybody please suggest me? So, I can take case of the requirement.

Comment: Just RTFM: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772080.aspx

Answer (score 0):

VS2013 will natively support 2010 and 2013, but it is possible to support 2007 as well.

Per Microsoft's article on [running solutions in different version's of Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772080(v=vs.120).aspx):

> If you developed solutions for Office 2010, you can run the same solutions in Microsoft Office 2013. If your customer base uses the 2007 Microsoft Office system, you can use Visual Studio 2013 to develop solutions that work in all three versions of Office. In this scenario, the solution will run without errors in the 2007 Microsoft Office system only if the solution doesn’t use features that are new in later versions of Office. Microsoft Office applications can also run solutions that were created by using a previous version of Visual Studio.