# Does VSTO Add-In support to Mac(iOS) Operating system?

Tags: c#, vsto

I have created a VSTO Add-In. It will add new Tab to ribbon. Currently, it is working fine in Windows system.

I don't know whether it supports to Mac(iOS) operating system.

Can anybody please suggest me about it support? If it doesn't, what I should use to create project which support both windows and Mac(iOS)?[image]

Answer (score 11):

The straight answer is that VSTO add-ins are based on the COM technology which doesn't exist on MACs. It is for Windows OS only. VSTO in particular and COM addins in general donot have the ability to work on the Mac OS or in iOS.
The architecture needed to invoke add-ins based on .NET controls is fundamentally different from the BSD Unix based ones that Mac uses.

The twist to this answer is if you are willing to stretch your programming towards [Office Apps](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins)  you will get what you are looking for.

This brief from MS will help you with the requirements for OS X desktop

> Word for Mac version 15.18 (160109) is required to run Office add-ins.
>
> Excel for Mac version 15.19 (160206) is required to run Office
>   add-ins.

Source : https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/requirements-for-running-office-add-ins

Comment: In that case, what will be compatibility of minimum version support? Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37212412/what-is-minimum-version-support-to-ms-office-of-vsto-add-in-created-in-vs-2013/37221649#37221649

Comment: My add-in contain new ribbon tab as its functionality. I think Office add-ins doesn't provide Ribbon tab functionality.