# Accessing C# libraries from Office Web Add-Ins

Tags: c#, .net, office365, vsto, office-js

Is there a standard way to access a C# (or VB.NET) library from an Office 365 Web Add-In?  I have a very large VSTO Word Add-In with a substantial amount of code written in C#, so I need to know if I can re-use this functionality without having to rewrite it all.

Comment: Pretty unlikely I’m afraid, particularly if you’re relying a lot on the object model. They’re very different paradigms, vsto and the office web addins

Comment: it's not possible for an Office Web Add-in to talk to a VSTO

Comment: I understand that perfectly.  I don't want to do that.  What I want to do is to access the *supporting libraries* that I currently consume within my VSTO add-in in my Web Add-In.

Comment: How about exposing the supported library code via a web API that your OfficeJS add-in can use? There are drawbacks, mostly related to the latency introduced by having to use HTTP. Another option is [using a custom XML part to communicate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.customxmlpart?view=office-js#addhandlerasync-eventtype--handler--options--callback-) between the VSTO add-in and OfficeJS add-in. Basically delegating requests from the OfficeJS add-in to the VSTO add-in, until your OfficeJS add-in is able to perform those requests itself.

Comment: That sounds interesting.  We make extensive use of custom xml parts already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes -- see this Microsoft tutorial on this:

[Tutorial: Share code between both a VSTO Add-in and an Office Add-in with a shared code library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/migrate-vsto-to-office-add-in-shared-code-library-tutorial)

In a nutshell, you use REST APIs to call your libraries written in C# from your new Web add-in written in JavaScript or TypeScript. This allows you to use those libraries for both your VSTO and Web add-in, or while transitioning from one to the other, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid that it's not possible for an Office Web Add-in to talk to a VSTO add-in and call the code of the VSTO add-in. Among other reasons, Office Web Add-ins are intended to work cross-platform. They should run in Office for Mac, for example. That would not be possible if they have a dependency on a VSTO add-in. (See this SO question for more about that: [Does VSTO Add-In support to Mac(iOS) Operating system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37212959/does-vsto-add-in-support-to-macios-operating-system).)

Comment: It's not t so much the VSTO interop that I'm interested in.  I have some C# libraries that deal with some pretty esoteric data structures, and it's these that I need to be able to access.  So it's mainly vanilla C#.  Just a lot of it!

Comment: @deadlyvices As per my answer that I just posted, there is now a MS tutorial on how you can access your C# libraries from Web add-ins -- which may not have been available when you first asked this question back in 2019.